# IF AND function in excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a function in excel that will return the value "1" after conditions true. but excel is not accepting my argument. 
my function is as below

```
=IF(AND(CK2="1",VLOOKUP(Sheet3!H2,Sheet1!G:G,1,FALSE),"1","0"))
```

[image: Excel Error]

Comment: What are you expecting `VLOOKUP(Sheet3!H2,Sheet1!G:G,1,FALSE)` to return? At the moment your formula is simply doing `AND(CK2="1",VLOOKUP(Sheet3!H2,Sheet1!G:G,1,FALSE),"1","0")` inside of an `IF()` - you haven't included any `True` or `False` parameters for your `IF`

Comment: It also seems that you are missing a bracket after the Vlookup formula, assuming the last two arguments "1" and "0" are part of the If statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF` syntax,

`=IF(Logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false])`

So your formula should be,

`=IF(AND(CK2="1",VLOOKUP(Sheet3!H2,Sheet1!G:G,1,FALSE)),"1","0")`

Comment: @iramakbar please mark my answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

`IF` takes 3 arguments; you have given it 1.  Check your parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have quotes in the search value "1"? 
Additional what kind of separator do you have? , or ;?
First close the AND statement! 
Here your line worked in excel 2016.
=IF(AND(CK2=1;VLOOKUP(Sheet3!H2;Sheet1!G:G;1;FALSE));1;0)